# Android - Singly dependencies

Tags: android, eclipse, noclassdeffounderror, buildpath

I'm trying to integrate my Android application with Singly, but I am getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` for `StringUtils`, which is used by SinglyClient.  I am pretty sure this is an issue with the way I configured my build path or set up the SDKs for Facebook and Singly.  Here is basically my setup:

**Directory Structure:**

```
parent-dir/
    MyApp/
    MyTestApp/
    facebook-android-sdk/
    singly-android-sdk/
```

The `facebook-android-sdk` is actually the directory `facebook-android-sdk/facebook` from the [Github repo](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk), and `singly-android-sdk` is actually the directory `singly-android/sdk` from the [Github repo](https://github.com/Singly/singly-android).  All of these have been imported into my workspace in Eclipse, though not copied.  As per the instructions [here](https://www.singly.com/docs/appfabric/getting_started_android), the Facebook SDK was imported via `Android -> Existing code...` and the Singly SDK was imported via `General -> Existing projects...`

**Facebook SDK Configuration**

```
Android:
    ✓ Is Library
Java Build Path:
    Source:
        FacebookSDK/gen
        FacebookSDK/src
    Libraries/Android Private Libraries:
        android-support-v4.jar
```

**Singly SDK Configuration**

```
Android:
    ✓ Is Library
    +-------------------------+-------------+
    | Reference               | Project     |
    +-------------------------+-------------+
    | ../facebook-android-sdk | FacebookSDK |
    +-------------------------+-------------+
Java Build Path:
    Source:
        SinglyAndroidSDK/gen
        SinglyAndroidSDK/src
    Libraries:
        Android Dependencies:
            facebooksdk.jar - /path/to/facebook-android-sdk/bin
        Android Private Libraries:
            < Big collection of jars here - will call this SinglyJarCollection>
Project References:
    ✓ Facebook SDK
```

**MyApp Configuration**

```
Android:
    +-----------------------+------------------+
    | Reference             | Project          |
    +-----------------------+------------------+
    | ../singly-android-sdk | SinglyAndroidSDK |
    +-----------------------+------------------+
Java Build Path:
    Source:
        MyApp/gen
        MyApp/src
    Libraries:
        <SinglyJarCollection>
        Android Dependencies:
            singlyandroidsdk.jar - /path/to/singly-android-sdk/bin
            facebooksdk.jar - /path/to/facebook-android-sdk/bin
        Android Private Libraries:
            <Some jars on which my application depends>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong in this set up, but Eclipse reports no syntax errors and my .apk file installs fine and works.  However, when I click the "login" button I configured to call SinglyClient's `authenticate` method, I get this issue of `NoClassDefFoundError` for `StringUtils`, which is in one of the jar files on which Singly depends.